# Prove by induction (real analysis exercise)

Tags: real-analysis

it would be great if I could get some help with this one!

Prove by induction that:

$x_n > 2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $x_1 = 5$ and $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}$($\frac{4}{x_n} + x_n)$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x_n\gt 2$,

$$x_{n+1}=\frac 12\left(\frac{4}{x_n}+x_n\right)\gt \frac 12\cdot 2\sqrt{\frac{4}{x_n}\cdot x_n}=\frac 12\cdot 2\sqrt 4=2.$$

Comment: could you please share with me your toughs regarding your inequality? $... x_n) > \frac{1}{2}2...$ where does it come from?

Comment: This is the AM-GM inequality : For $a\gt 0,b\gt 0$, $(a+b)/2\ge \sqrt{ab}$ where the equality is attained only when $a=b$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Comment: AM-GM beautiful! :) Thanks!

Comment: @SergioSarmiento: You are welcome.

Comment: my last question is, in which way can I show that $a = b$?, which in my case will be: $\frac{4}{x_n} = x_n$

Comment: @SergioSarmiento: Note that $\frac{4}{x_n}=x_n\iff x_n^2=4\iff (x_n-2)(x_n+2)=0\iff x_n=\pm 2$. Now, we have $x_n\gt 2$, so $\frac{4}{x_n}\not =x_n$. Hence, $((4/x_n)+x_n)/2\gt \sqrt{(4/x_n)\cdot x_n}$. The equality does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for induction.

As $$
0\le (\sqrt a - \sqrt b)^2 = a + b - 2\sqrt{ab}, 
\\
\sqrt {ab} \le \frac{a + b}2
$$

Hence
$$
u_{n+1} = \frac {x_n + 4/x_n}2 \ge \sqrt{x_n\times 4/x_n} =2.
$$